# Databricks SQL mismatch issue with T-SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

When I appy the following query using T-SQL on MS Server I don't have any problems:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  *

FROM dbo.account
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.crm2cburl_lookup
  ON account.Id = CRM2CBURL_Lookup.[Key]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.organizations 
ON CRM2CBURL_Lookup.CB_URL_KEY = organizations.cb_url
cross apply (values (charindex('://', homepage_url))) a(a)
cross apply (values (iif(a = 0, 1, a + 3))) b(b)
cross apply (values (charindex('/', homepage_url, b))) c(c)
cross apply (values (iif(c = 0, len(homepage_url) + 1, c))) d(d)
cross apply (values (substring(homepage_url, b, d - b))) e(e)
```

However, when I apply the similar (identical except for the database used) I get the error message
missing 'JOIN' at 'apply'(line 14, pos 6)
line 14 refers to

```
cross apply (values (charindex('://', homepage_url))) a(a)
```

The query on Databricks is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  *

FROM basecrmcbreport.account
LEFT OUTER JOIN basecrmcbreport.crm2cburl_lookup
  ON account.Id = crm2cburl_lookup.Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN basecrmcbreport.organizations 
ON crm2cburl_lookup.CB_URL_KEY = organizations.cb_url
cross apply (values (charindex('://', homepage_url))) a(a)
cross apply (values (iif(a = 0, 1, a + 3))) b(b)
cross apply (values (charindex('/', homepage_url, b))) c(c)
cross apply (values (iif(c = 0, len(homepage_url) + 1, c))) d(d)
cross apply (values (substring(homepage_url, b, d - b))) e(e)
```

My feeling the problem is a syntax error with 'charindex', but I'm not sure.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have use **cross apply** for demo employee and department tables I have created and I have got the same error.

**missing ‘JOIN’ at  ‘APPLY’**

[image]

most queries which employ **CROSS APPLY** can be rewritten using an **INNER JOIN** as both of them yield same output.

```
select * from department d inner join employee e on d.dept_id=e.dep_id;
```

[image]